# Angle between tangent of Hyperbola and Xaxis

Tags: calculus, geometry

The problem is to find the angle between x axis and tangent to the hyperbola xy=9 at (3,3).

The angle made by slope of the tangent of hyperbola at (3,3) is the angle between x-axis and tangent ?

Comment: What do you mean by "angle made by slope of the tangent"? If I had to guess I would guess you meant the angle between the $x$-axis and the tangent, but you're not sure about that. Perhaps if you calculated the angle and showed how you did it, it would be clear whether you had found the angle you need.

Answer (score 3):

1) Another way of writing the equation of this hyperbola is $$y=\frac{9}{x} \quad .$$

2) Differentiate this to give $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}= \quad ? \qquad .$$

3) To find the slope of the tangent, $m, $at $(x,y)=(3,3),$ plug in $x=3$ into $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

4) The angle between this tangent line at $(3,3), $ and the $x$-axis, $\theta$, is given by $$\tan(\theta)=m.$$

Now solve for $\theta.$

Comment: That's exactly what I did. The answer is -45 degrees.

Comment: @deepthought Nice! That's right!